# jQuery Mobile wait until page list-view loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm currently developing a small JQM + PhoneGap app (new at this) and got the following issue, I'm loading data from a JSON (which is local, no AJAX yet) to a list-view, the problem comes when I load the  page the css of the list-view takes a little time to load and you can see the bulleted list for a half of a second. Here is a portion of the code which I think is involved

```html
<div data-role="content" id="job_offers_close_to_user_result">
    <!-- Insert job offers from JSON script here -->
    <div id="fill_with_job_offers_close_to_user_result"></div>
    <div id="view_job_offer_button"></div>
</div>
```

```js
AppController.fillJobsList = function(){
$("#view_job_offer_button").append(" ");
$("#fill_with_job_offers_close_to_user_result").html(" ");
for (var i=0; i < JSON_with_jobs.ofertas.length; i++){
    $("#fill_with_job_offers_close_to_user_result").append("<ul data-role='listview'>"
        + "<li><a href='#job_description_"+i+"'>"
        + JSON_with_jobs.ofertas[i].titulo + "<br />"
        + JSON_with_jobs.ofertas[i].empresa + "<br />"
        + JSON_with_jobs.ofertas[i].contrato + "<br />"
        + JSON_with_jobs.ofertas[i].localidad + "," + JSON_with_jobs.ofertas[i].provincia + "<br />"
        + "<br />"
        +"</a></li>"
        + "</ul>"
);
```

This function is triggered when clicked a button

```html
<a id="mybutton2" onclick="AppController.fillJobsList()" href="#close_to_user" data-role="button">Buscar</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need to _enhance_ listview before appending it http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d93ucgbj/ another method http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hrqtkocd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the element as with style code "display:none;" and after you finish appending the element and finish proccessing it, to show it

```
$(element).show();
```